# Find maximum values in array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I'm unable to find the correct words to describe my problem. I have an array of values which are increasing 'in groups/locally':

```
[1,2,3,4,5, 2,3,4,5, 4,5,6,6,10, 0,100,1000, 999]
```

I want to extract the maximum from each 'local group', so for the above example, the answer would be:

```
[5,5,10,1000,999]
```

I can iterate through and find pairs where `previous.value >= next.value`, slice it and extract `max` from each group, but I want to know the better way :). If you know name of this problem, please share

Comment: That approach seems optimal; I doubt a better way exists.

Comment: Derp, thank you for pointing this out

Comment: That indeed appears to be optimal. Consider a private case of continuously decreasing values, e.g. 5,4,3,2,1. Here each group has exactly one element in it and it's also the maximum, i.e., the output will be the same as the input and you must iterate through **all** values.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long int
int main(){
    ll n;
    //length of an array
    cin>>n;
    ll a[n];
    ll i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        if(a[i]<a[i-1]){
            cout<<a[i-1]<<" ";
        }
    }
    //Last element always be a local maximum
    cout<<a[n-1]; 
   //I think this will help you
}
```

Comment: @DavidBuck It doesn't solve the question. It's just an implementation of the method that the OP knows. The question is whether there is a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: I think O(N) is the best complexity .